# SQL Backup files, distinguish partial and full backup files

Tags: c#, sql, database-backups

I have scheduled backups running through SQL Agent, with Full Backups nightly, and differential backups hourly.  Is there a way to determine which of the backup files is the Full backup, and which is the latest differential?

Intuitively, it would seem the largest backup within 24 hours is the full, and the latest smaller backup is the partial.  However, this isn't robust.

Is there a way to probe the backup file to check the backup type?  (Preferably in c#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK'
```

Then check the **BackupType**

```
1 = Database
2 = Transaction log
4 = File
5 = Differential database
6 = Differential file
7 = Partial
8 = Differential partial
```

**Referrences**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536.aspx
- http://www.mssqltips.com/tutorial.asp?tutorial=105

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give this a shot.  Though, from the two links I have no doubt it will work.